# Validate Credit Card Number Using Luhn Algorithm Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement Luhn algorithm in Python. Here is my code

```
def validate(n):
    if len(str(n)) > 16:
        return False
    else:
        if len(str(n)) % 2 == 0:
            for i in str(n[0::2]):
                digit = int(str(n[i])) * 2
                while digit > 9:
                    digit = sum(map(int, str(digit)))
            dig_sum = sum(map(int, str(n)))
            return True if dig_sum % 10 == 0 else False
        elif len(str(n)) % 2 != 0:
            for i in str(n[1::2]):
                digit = int(str(n[i])) * 2
                while digit > 9:
                    digit = sum(map(int, str(digit)))
            dig_sum = sum(map(int, str(n)))
            return True if dig_sum % 10 == 0 else False
```

I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__
```

Comment: There is a Python implementation on the Wikipedia page for the [Luhn Algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Verification_of_the_check_digit)

Comment: How are you passing `n`? as an integer number? If so look at the first for loop. There you have the expression `digit = int(str(n[i])) * 2`. If `n` is a simple integer this will generate your error. You cant index the digits before converting to string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29197921/2141635

Comment: To debug, print type of the variable for which u r using index. __getitem__ should be implemented for indexing to work. Thats what the error says.

Answer (score 3):

Following is python implementation of Lunh Algorith to detect a valid credit card number.  Function takes a number as string and return whether its valid credit card or not.

Its based on the steps mentioned in the following link: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/515367/Validate-credit-card-number-with-Mod-algorithm

Step 1 - Starting with the check digit double the value of every other digit (right to left every 2nd digit)

Step 2 - If doubling of a number results in a two digits number, add up the digits to get a single digit number. This will results in eight single digit numbers.

Step 3 - Now add the un-doubled digits to the odd places

Step 4 - Add up all the digits in this number

If the final sum is divisible by 10, then the credit card number is valid. If it is not divisible by 10, the number is invalid.

```
def luhn(ccn):
    c = [int(x) for x in ccn[::-2]] 
    u2 = [(2*int(y))//10+(2*int(y))%10 for y in ccn[-2::-2]]
    return sum(c+u2)%10 == 0

#Test
print(luhn("49927398716"))
```

Comment: Algo here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/515367/Validate-credit-card-number-with-Mod-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without the complete error message, but it is likely because you confused in some places where you put the indexing and where you put the string conversion, for example: `for i in str(**n[1::2]**)` and `digit = int(str(**n[i]**)) * 2`

A good way to handle it is to just create a temporary variable `n_str = str(n)`, and use it instead of str(n) over and over again.