# Luhns Algorithm

Tags: python, luhn

Hey I am doing Luhn's algorithm for an assignment for school.

A few outputs are coming out the correct way; however, some are not.

`0004222222222222` is giving me a total of `44`,

and

`0378282246310005` is giving me a total of `48`,

for a few examples.

I know my code isn't the cleanest as I am a novice but if anyone can identify where I'm getting my error I'd really appreciate

Here is my code:

```
cardNumber = input( "What is your card number? ")
digit = len(cardNumber)
value = 0
total = 0
while ( len( cardNumber ) == 16 and digit > 0):
    # HANDLE even digit positions
    if ( digit % 2 == 0 ):
        value = ( int( cardNumber[digit - 1]) * 2 )
        if( value > 9 ):
            double = str( value )
            value = int( double[:1] ) + int( double[-1] )
            total = total + value
            value = 0
            digit = digit - 1
        else:
            total = total + value
            value = 0
            digit = digit - 1
    # HANDLE odd digit positions
    elif ( digit % 2 != 0):
        total = total + int( cardNumber[digit - 1] )
        digit = digit - 1
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to why these output are not correct? What should they be?

Comment: there is a python implementation of the algorithm in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), you can study it and try to see if you can identify the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197219/credit-card-number-validator-doesnt-work-correctly/29197921#29197921

Comment: Nice question. All the best on SO for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. Only that the last digit (or first from behind) should be considered as odd for your 16 digit card. So you should set:

```
digit = len(cardNumber) - 1
```

And then your *while* condition should stop at `>= 0` (zeroth item inclusive); note that the `len( cardNumber ) == 16` is redundant as the length of the card is constant:

```
while digit >= 0:
```

And finally your indexing of the creditcard number will no longer need a minus 1:

```
value = int(cardNumber[digit]) * 2
...
...
total = total + int(cardNumber[digit])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply! At least I know now.
 The assignment was due an hour and a half ago I was foolish enough to just check this now lol. Was playing Diablo for ps1 on the raspberry pi all night /facepalm

Comment: @BrianUpward Accepting helpful answers on SO is another way of saying thank you

Comment: Do I have to click so et

Comment: Do I have to click something to accept it? I upvoted it already

Comment: @BrianUpward It is pretty easy :) See [How do I accept an answer on stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

So your code is mostly correct, the only issue is that you haven't properly defined what should be considered an "odd" and an "even" number. As you read the number from the end, "odd and even" are also relative from the end, so  :

- odd numbers start from the *last one*, and then every other one
- even numbers start from the *last but one*, and then every other one

Example : 1234 is EOEO, 12345 is OEOEO (O means odd , E means even)

Here the fixed code (I only modified three lines, see comments):

```
digit = len(cardNumber)
value = 0
total = 0
while  digit > 0: # I removed the length condition
    # HANDLE even digit positions
    if ( (len(cardNumber)+1-digit) % 2 == 0 ): # <- modification here
        value = ( int( cardNumber[digit - 1]) * 2 )
        if( value > 9 ):
            double = str( value )
            value = int( double[:1] ) + int( double[-1] )
            total = total + value
            digit = digit - 1
        else:
            total = total + value
            digit = digit - 1

    # HANDLE odd digit positions
    elif ( (len(cardNumber)+1-digit) % 2 != 0): # <- modification here
        value=int( cardNumber[digit - 1] )
        total = total + int( cardNumber[digit - 1] )
        digit = digit - 1

return total
```

Some tests :

```
In : '0378282246310005' ->  Out : 60
In : '00378282246310005' ->  Out : 60
In : '0004222222222222' ->  Out : 40
```